# Create a new column from one of the value available in another columns as an array of Key Value pair

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have extracted some data from hive to dataframe, which is in the below shown format.

```
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------+
| NUM_ID|            SIG1|           SIG2|             SIG3|            SIG4|
+----------------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+
|XXXXX01|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX02|[{15695604780...|[{15695604780...|[{15695604780...|[{15695604780...|
|XXXXX03|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX04|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX05|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX06|[{15695605340...|[{15695605340...|[{15695605340...|[{15695605340...|
|XXXXX07|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX08|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
```

If we take only one signal it will be as below.

```
|XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|
    [{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560481000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|
    [{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560527000,34.7825}]|
    [{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560479000,34.7825},{1569560487000,34.7825}]
```

For each NUM_ID , each SIG column will have an array of E and V pairs.

The schema for the above data is

```
fromHive.printSchema
root
|-- NUM_ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- SIG1: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
|-- SIG2: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
|-- SIG3: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
|-- SIG4: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
```

My requirement is to get the all E values from all the columns for a particular NUM_ID and create as a new cloumn with corresponding signal values in another columns as shown below.

```
+-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| NUM_ID|            E| SIG1_V| SIG2_V| SIG3_V| SIG4_V|
+-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|XXXXX01|1569560531000|33.7825|34.7825|   null|96.3354|
|XXXXX01|1569560505000|   null|   null|35.5501|   null|
|XXXXX01|1569560531001|73.7825|   null|   null|   null|
|XXXXX02|1569560505000|34.7825|   null|35.5501|96.3354|
|XXXXX02|1569560531000|33.7825|34.7825|35.5501|96.3354|
|XXXXX02|1569560505001|73.7825|   null|   null|   null|
|XXXXX02|1569560502000|   null|   null|35.5501|96.3354|
|XXXXX03[1569560531000|73.7825|   null|   null|   null|
|XXXXX03|1569560505000|34.7825|   null|35.5501|96.3354|
|XXXXX03|1569560509000|   null|34.7825|35.5501|96.3354|
```

The E values from all four signals column, for a particular NUM_ID should be taken as a single column without duplicates and the V values for corresponding E should be populated in different columns. Suppose a Signal is not having any E-V pair for a particular E, then that column should be null. as shown above.

Thanks in advance. Any lead appreciated.

For better Understanding below is the sample structure for input and expected output.

INPUT:

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| NUM_ID|             SIG1|           SIG2|             SIG3|            SIG4|
+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
|XXXXX01|[{E1,V1},{E2,V2}]|[{E1,V3},{E3,V4}]|[{E4,V5},{E5,V6}]|[{E5,V7},{E2,V8}] |
|XXXXX02|[{E7,V1},{E8,V2}]|[{E1,V3},{E3,V4}]|[{E1,V5},{E5,V6}]|[{E9,V7},{E8,V8}]|
|XXXXX03|[{E1,V1},{E2,V2}]|[{E1,V3},{E3,V4}]|[{E4,V5},{E5,V6}]|[{E5,V7},{E2,V8}] |
```

OUTPUT EXPECTED:

```
+-------+---+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| NUM_ID|  E| SIG1_V| SIG2_V| SIG3_V| SIG4_V|
+-------+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|XXXXX01| E1|     V1|     V3|   null|   null|
|XXXXX01| E2|     V2|   null|   null|     V8|
|XXXXX01| E3|   null|     V4|   null|   null|
|XXXXX01| E4|   null|   null|     V5|   null|
|XXXXX01| E5|   null|   null|     V6|     V7|

|XXXXX02| E1|   null|     V3|     V5|   null|
|XXXXX02| E3|   null|     V4|   null|   null|
|XXXXX02| E5|   null|   null|     V6|   null|
|XXXXX02[ E7|     V1|   null|   null|   null|
|XXXXX02| E8|     V2|   null|   null|     V7|
|XXXXX02| E9|   null|34.7825|   null|     V8|
```

Comment: @Nikk- Is it possible by writing a UDF which took input parameter as Row?

Comment: yes you can pass compete row in UDF. Please let me know if you want any lead for that.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output of the data that you have provided as input. It seems like there is a discrepancy in Input and Output data. I can see there are four possible value of E in SIG1 for XXXXX01 in input but getting different output

Comment: I have given a sample data as expected output. it is not exactly the output of given input data

Comment: @Nikk- Yes I tried writing UDF for by passing a row and unable to proceed. If u can provide some lead it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Input CSV file is as below:

NUM_ID|SIG1|SIG2|SIG3|SIG4 XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

    val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter", "|").load("path .csv")
    df.show(false)
    +-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |NUM_ID |SIG1                                                                                          |SIG2                                                                                            |SIG3                                                                                             |SIG4                                                                     |
    +-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|
    +-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    //UDF to generate column E

    def UDF_E:UserDefinedFunction=udf((r: Row)=>{
    val SigColumn = "SIG1,SIG2,SIG3,SIG4"
    val colList = SigColumn.split(",").toList
    val rr = "[\\}],[\\{]".r
    var out = ""
    colList.foreach{ x =>
    val a = (rr replaceAllIn(r.getAs(x).toString, "|")).replaceAll("\\[\\{","").replaceAll("\\}\\]","")
    val b = a.split("\\|").map(x => x.split(",")(0)).toSet
    out = out + "," + b.mkString(",")
    }
    val out1 = out.replaceFirst(s""",""","").split(",").toSet.mkString(",")
    out1
    })


    //UDF to generate column value with Signal

    def UDF_V:UserDefinedFunction=udf((E: String, SIG:String)=>{
    val Signal = SIG.replaceAll("\\{", "\\(").replaceAll("\\}", "\\)").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")
    val SigMap = "(\\w+),([\\w 0-9 .]+)".r.findAllIn(Signal).matchData.map(i => {(i.group(1), i.group(2))}).toMap
    var out = ""
    if(SigMap.keys.toList.contains(E)){
    out = SigMap(E).toString
    }
    out})

    //new DataFrame with Column "E"
    val df1 = df.withColumn("E", UDF_E(struct(df.columns map col: _*))).withColumn("E", explode(split(col("E"), ",")))

     df1.show(false)
    +-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
    |NUM_ID |SIG1                                                                                          |SIG2                                                                                            |SIG3                                                                                             |SIG4                                                                     |E            |
    +-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560483000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560497000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560475000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560489000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560535000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560531000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560513000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560537000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560491000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560521000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560505000|
    +-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+

    //Final DataFrame
    val df2 =  df1.withColumn("SIG1_V", UDF_V(col("E"),col("SIG1"))).withColumn("SIG2_V", UDF_V(col("E"),col("SIG2"))).withColumn("SIG3_V", UDF_V(col("E"),col("SIG3"))).withColumn("SIG4_V", UDF_V(col("E"),col("SIG4"))).drop("SIG1","SIG2","SIG3","SIG4")

    df2.show()
    +-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    | NUM_ID|            E| SIG1_V| SIG2_V| SIG3_V| SIG4_V|
    +-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |XXXXX01|1569560475000| 3.7812|       |       |       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560483000| 3.7812|       |       |34.7825|
    |XXXXX01|1569560489000|       |34.7825|       |       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560491000|34.7875|       |       |       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560497000|       |34.7825|       |       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560505000|       |       |34.7825|       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560513000|       |       |34.7825|       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560521000|       |       |34.7825|       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560531000| 3.7825|34.7825|34.7825|34.7825|
    |XXXXX01|1569560535000|       |       |       |34.7825|
    |XXXXX01|1569560537000|       | 3.7825|       |       |
    +-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: @Antony I have uses regex "(\\w+),([\\w 0-9 .]+)" which might be required to change if your data get change. If data will be in format {1569560531000,3.7825} then there is no issue.

Comment: @Nikk- The below part which create array of **E** is giving me output as below, which do not have all the E available for all signals.
```val df1 = df.withColumn("E", UDF_E(struct(df.columns map col: _*)))```
E column as below
```|WrappedArray([1570180028000,WrappedArray([1570180017000|```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct code because I have tried to replicate same issue but it is giving me correct result.Can you run same code with the dataframe that I have used (check above code for dataframe df) and confirm it working or not. I have kept csv file please copy it  somewhere and read as I mentioned an run all above command.

Comment: This is the o/p for val **out = out+","+a** 
```|354476053762294     |[[1570180028000, 53.0], [1570180027000, 53.0], [1570179967000, 53.0]]|[[1570180028000, 58.0], [1570179968000, 58.0], [1570179967000, 58.0]]|[[1570180028000, 58.0], [1570179968000, 58.0], [1570179967000, 58.0]]|[[1570180028000, 59.0], [1570179968000, 59.0], [1570179967000, 59.0]]|[[1570180028000, 57.0], [1570179968000, 57.0], [1570179967000, 57.0]]|[[1570180017000, 58.0], [1570179968000, 58.0], [1570179967000, 58.0]]|,WrappedArray([1570180028000,53.0], ```

Comment: ```[1570180027000,53.0], [1570179967000,53.0]),WrappedArray([1570180028000,58.0], [1570179968000,58.0], [1570179967000,58.0]),WrappedArray([1570180028000,58.0], [1570179968000,58.0], [1570179967000,58.0]),WrappedArray([1570180028000,59.0], [1570179968000,59.0], [1570179967000,59.0]),WrappedArray([1570180028000,57.0], [1570179968000,57.0], [1570179967000,57.0]),WrappedArray([1570180017000,58.0], [1570179968000,58.0], [1570179967000,58.0])|```

Comment: below is the output for **out = out+","+b**
```|354476053762294     |[[1570180028000, 53.0], [1570180027000, 53.0], [1570179967000, 53.0]]|[[1570180028000, 58.0], [1570179968000, 58.0], [1570179967000, 58.0]]|[[1570180028000, 58.0], [1570179968000, 58.0], [1570179967000, 58.0]]|[[1570180028000, 59.0], [1570179968000, 59.0], [1570179967000, 59.0]]|[[1570180028000, 57.0], [1570179968000, 57.0], [1570179967000, 57.0]]|[[1570180017000, 58.0], [1570179968000, 58.0], [1570179967000, 58.0]]|,Set(WrappedArray([1570180028000),Set(WrappedArray([1570180028000),Set(WrappedArray([1570180028000),```

Comment: ```Set(WrappedArray([1570180028000),Set(WrappedArray([1570180028000),Set(WrappedArray([1570180017000)|```

Comment: @Nikk- It seems like spliting **a** and maping it to set is having some error!

Comment: it is because i am creating a Set ... if you change any data condition then there it different issue otherwise it will work always.  I am understanding  why you are getting such value. could you provide data that you are using getting this.

Comment: happy to hear :)